# Including "prompt=consent" on Office 365 OAuth authorization request for resource "https://graph.microsoft.com/" generates an error

Tags: ms-office, office365, azure-active-directory

I'm moving our existing Office365 API usage over to the Unified API (at https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0).

For reasons explained in [Adding an additional Windows Azure AD delegated permission to an existing grant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025263/adding-an-additional-windows-azure-ad-delegated-permission-to-an-existing-grant), I need to include `prompt=consent` in my authorization request Url, and so up until now my authorization Url has looked like:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3a%2f%2fgraph.windows.net%2f&prompt=consent&client_id=ec49c780-6767-46f2-8697-bdd816e42504&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.airhead.io%2fservices%2freply%2foffice365%2foauth&scope=UserProfile.Read+Calendars.Read+Files.Read+Sites.Read.All+Mail.Read&response_type=code`

..which (after auth and consent) returns me to something like:

`https://login.airhead.io/services/reply/office365/oauth?code=AAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLeSvP6UG3gEwceCQ8hU_03hUjXRvPUfs_Y-324csuR0rDFE-qdNIsD0on-DjKGoSzvVL4PKh7_uQkghxtOGCZGEJ7GwcUDpvoHH86pjct3vAb94wPt8Pkdm46HhvPeBn6JDrK5VIBYdwxS2r8dLRmjqiyIBbGZDsOUCDymeFebYsFc-V39sQ9WFSx5ErjIeHvZ_Qf4zB1SDjT-iEqJPTW7H5bZpvFJQHhUqn3TvVL37Up4ZzkWxz5fb0zMk_7yKuz6G-DW6kz_Y1S30ZNgO45maDEw9KBqmdIR_NeewmFSKokgF4Unsfi__xNzjf6xO6VcMOidych7V7uQi_jxX7zP5hLvXgAoNmqBU-AnV2NVZ-5tq2s4w8vvl61TXUjR1MtwVf4TzcsL55uvyP16lid6JpWsdssZvWJNXna_zJC0Ok629vE5-4pzu-zF5C_PJztkx8VQ8QDmP4_JqkHkRmq2zO0doY25AF6Sh3odyNEx6IwWxe9jirPv_8NfwlmldYnpItzbmYlqLilOIEBNXpESgUmPz02A0Czu--pZP45JfjNDrVnUBBV9liPToK_QPe99xOSNHmk70h171M5BjVnhggAA&session_state=8494e152-60ab-4ddc-a247-ee55798e0595`

..which allows me to continue with the flow, using the code auth'd against the old `https://graph.windows.net/` resource. All good.

However, after modifying the `resource` param value on the authorization Url to `https://graph.microsoft.com/` to authorize against the new Unified API, i.e.:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3a%2f%2fgraph.microsoft.com%2f&prompt=consent&client_id=ec49c780-6767-46f2-8697-bdd816e42504&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.airhead.io%2fservices%2freply%2foffice365%2foauth&scope=UserProfile.Read+Calendars.Read+Files.Read+Sites.Read.All+Mail.Read&response_type=code`

..I'm returned an error response:

`https://login.airhead.io/services/reply/office365/oauth?error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS65005%3a+The+client+application+has+requested+access+to+resource+%27https%3a%2f%2fgraph.microsoft.com%2f%27.+This+request+has+failed+because+the+client+has+not+specified+this+resource+in+its+requiredResourceAccess+list.%0D%0ATrace+ID%3a+d9cc9773-feb5-42b4-9414-eaf64620fc0f%0D%0ACorrelation+ID%3a+ea1f37de-35bb-4b41-af49-c877dda75d11%0D%0ATimestamp%3a+2016-01-18+13%3a15%3a18Z`

..with description "AADSTS65005: The client application has requested access to resource 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'. This request has failed because the client has not specified this resource in its requiredResourceAccess list".

If I try the same authorization Url (against resource `https://graph.microsoft.com/` again), but drop the `prompt=consent` param this time, i.e:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3a%2f%2fgraph.microsoft.com%2f&client_id=ec49c780-6767-46f2-8697-bdd816e42504&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.airhead.io%2fservices%2freply%2foffice365%2foauth&scope=UserProfile.Read+Calendars.Read+Files.Read+Sites.Read.All+Mail.Read&response_type=code`

..it works.

The documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/dn645542.aspx still suggests that `prompt=consent` is valid, so is the documentation wrong (i.e. I can't use `prompt=consent` with resource `https://graph.microsoft.com/`) or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's a whole new set of scopes for v1.0 of graph.microsoft.com, which weren't needed during the preview. Adding these scopes to my app manifest resolved the issue. (facepalm)